# How do I toggle between a "show more" and "show less" while having button element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a personal project. I have few articles in a same page, that have pretty large amount of text (not that big though). What I want is toggling the button. Once the button is clicked the additional text should be displayed and the button value have to be changed (i.e. from `continue reading` to `show less` or something similar.) And again after clicking the button, the additional text have to be collapsed. In addition to that I want to add some slow motion while toggling between the text. How could I do that?
The example in the internet I have seen so far does not relate what I am expecting to achieve. Most demo and examples in the internet use the text property (e.g. simple `show more` and `show less` text), not the button element as I do.

```
 <article class="post">
                <header>
                    <div class="title">
                        <h2><a href="index.html">Who am I? What am I? Why am I?</a></h2>
                        <p>Sub Header</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="meta">
                        <time class="published" datetime="2017-01-14">November 1, 2017</time>
                        <a href="#" class="author"><span class="name">John Doe</span><img src="images/author-avatar.png" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
                </header>
                <a href="index.html" class="image featured"><img src="images/who_iam.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <p>Default text<br>
                 Toggle this text. Show this text when "continue reading" button is clicked. Once the button is clicked change the button value to "read less". Once the "read less" button is clicked hide this text.

     </p>
               <footer>
                  <ul class="actions">
                        <li><a href="" class="button big">Continue Reading</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </footer>
            </article>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your are using jQuery then -

1. Initially hide the content with CSS.
2. Add `slideToggle` to hidden content on click event.

Here is a demo -> https://codepen.io/thesumit67/pen/wemjPG

Answer (score 1):

You should create a button, with a simple javascript functiom:

```js
visible = false; //var that keeps track if the content is visible.
txt = document.getElementById("text");
btn = document.getElementById("btn");
function toggle() {
  if(visible) {
    visible = 0;
    btn.innerHTML = 'Show more';
    txt.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    visible = 1;
    btn.innerHTML = 'Show Less';
    txt.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
 <article class="post">
                <header>
                    <div class="title">
                        <h2><a href="index.html">Who am I? What am I? Why am I?</a></h2>
                        <p>Sub Header</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="meta">
                        <time class="published" datetime="2017-01-14">November 1, 2017</time>
                        <a href="#" class="author"><span class="name">John Doe</span><img src="images/author-avatar.png" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
                </header>
                <a href="index.html" class="image featured"><img src="images/who_iam.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                 <p>Default text</p>
                <p id='text' style='display: none;'>
                 Toggle this text. Show this text when "continue reading" button is clicked. Once the button is clicked change the button value to "read less". Once the "read less" button is clicked hide this text.

     </p>
               <footer>
                  <ul class="actions">
                        <li><button id='btn' onclick='toggle()'>Show More</button></li>
                    </ul>

                </footer>
            </article>
```